# PHP cookie control does not work correctly

Tags: cookies

I created a custom cookie banner for my WordPress site and it works perfectly. However, now I have a small problem. With PHP I'm trying to make it invisible to users who have already accepted it. To do this I use the following code that checks if the cookie is already present or not:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookieSet'])) {
?>
   <div class="cookie-banner-background active">
      <!--HTML code for cookie banner-->
      ...
   </div>
   <script>
      /*JS code for activating the cookie banner and setting cookies with the various chosen cookies*/
      ...
   </script>
<?php
}
```

What I would like to achieve:

1. User comes to the site and accepts cookies [it works];
2. The "cookieSet" cookie is installed on the user's device [it works];
3. The page reloads in the same position in which it was reloaded with the new instructions [it works];
4. At the new loading of the page the HTML code of the cookie banner must disappear [it DOESN'T work].

Practically even if the cookie has already been installed it seems as if that IF in PHP sees it NOT installed.

**Note:** the cookie banner disappears anyway because I applied a JS code that does it, but the JS code loads with a few milliseconds of delay and if you reload the page again you will see the cookie banner appear for a short time.

The strange thing is that if you go to any other page on my site configured the same way on the other pages the PHP IF code will work correctly.

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of your cookie banner I don't see how this can be answered, can you include the code?

Comment: The cookie banner code is inserted inside the IF indicated in the question. The code inside works. What doesn't work is the PHP code that seems to not be read correctly on the first page only. This means that on all the others on my site it works correctly.

Comment: Is there perhaps a code that allows you to reset the PHP code cache? So that at the refresh of the page it works correctly?

Comment: imo opcache is irrelevant, please edit your question to include all the code, your if statement isn't enough, e.g. there's no information about what sets the cookie, where the cookie is set, how the cookie is set, the value the cookie has, etc. There's also no information about the kind of caching you have, if you're using a CDN such as cloudflare or software such as Varnish or a page cache etc. It might seem like it should be as simple as the if statement, and just fixing the if statement, but it isn't. Too much information is better than too little

Comment: Entering all the code makes no sense. I have however added a few more directions as you indicated.

I've already done all the relevant tests and I'm sure the problem comes from that IF string in PHP. It basically works on all pages except the one where you first land and where the cookie banner appears.

Comment: If, for example, I land on the "blog" page of the site for the first time and accept the cookie banner, the page is reloaded via the script document.location.reload(); and the cookie is set via the script document.cookie = 'cookieSet='+JSON.stringify(getData)+'; expires='+now.toUTCString()+'; SameSite=None; Secure; path=/';

Comment: But then the HTML code keeps showing up, even though the PHP code says that if there is cookie then it should not show it. And the strange thing is that of course the cookie is set. So I don't understand why the IF returns true and continues when it should return false and skip.

Comment: Is WP Rocket being used for full-page caching or for partials? Does turning it off fix the issue? There are settings in WP Rocket specifically for the handling of cookies https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1382-never-cache-cookies

Comment: I'm trying various tests, but it all seems useless. This is the URL of the site: https://sos-wp.it/

As you can see the cookie banner appears correctly and disappears immediately, but if you check in the code the HTML structure is still re-presented, while if you go to a page other than the home it disappears correctly as it should be. I don't understand, it's really strange.

Comment: You can find the cookie banner HTML code under the HTML tag "main" at the following tag: <div class="cookie-banner-background">

Comment: If you then go to any other page you see that the HTML for the cookie banner is no longer present, as indicated by the PHP string put in the question of this ticket. But why when you go back to the first page (in this case the home page) does the HTML still appear?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce what you describe on your site and could not reproduce it. As an aside, given that this change means you're unable to use page caching across the entire site, is this wise? The only time cached pages will ever be shown is when they first arrive and get the cookie prompt, but then as soon as they accept the page reloads and no cache is used, so the page caching is pointless

Comment: I updated the ticket again. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I see, but your desired behaviour is what I'm seeing on your website, in my tests it works! WP Rockets page cache is fundamentally incompatible with what you're trying to achieve here. As long as your cookie banner is using PHP/server side logic then WP Rocket page caching will either never work, or will never get used. When investigating this or placing blame, WP Rocket should be your primary target. IMO the fastest way for you to fix this is to disable WP Rocket page caching, or deactivate the WP Rocket plugin. Alternatively, use javascript not PHP to show/hide your consent UI

Comment: The TLDR: All your problems with this code are related to or caused by WP Rocket

Comment: Note: the cookie banner disappears anyway because I applied a JS code that does it, but the JS code loads with a few milliseconds of delay and if you reload the page again you will see the cookie banner appear for a short time.

Comment: I totally understand what you want to tell me about WP Rocket, I try to find a solution with their documentation.

Comment: I tried retesting and the _only_ way I could get the consent dialog to re-appear, was to go into my dev tools and delete the cookie. I am unable to reproduce this issue ( Google Chrome MacOS ). If your code is hiding it then it's doing it imperceptibly fast. I've been repeatedly reloading the page again and I do not see the banner appear for a short time.

Comment: I also loaded the page via `view-source` so that javascript would not run and can confirm that the `consenso-cookie-necessari` only appears once in a CSS snippet. However if I open an incognito browser it appears twice in the CSS and in the consent dialog. I suspect you are encountering browser cache issues, which could be confirmed by the HTML comment WP Rocket leaves behind. My recommendation is to move your consent UI into JS, perhaps always include the HTML but only unhide it using JS when there is no cookie. This would allow you to continue using full page caching

Comment: It's also possible the issue you're encountering is only happening to you and other logged in users. I can't test that theory from my location though